# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert' - i'm having trouble appending to a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, list

i'm trying to make a game, however i cannot figure out the code to go into

```
def deckgeneration(self):
fulldeck = [[]]
for i in range (1,deck):
    name =  takerandomline()
    speed = random.randint(1,5)
    strength = random.randint(1,100)
    agility = random.randint(1,10)
    flexibility = random.randint(1,10)
    fulldeck[i]= fulldeck.insert([name,speed,strength,agility,flexibility])
return fulldeck
```

to append the 5 variables into a 2D list for each count of 'i' since when I get to the 9th line in the above function it doesn't seem to work no matter what I try- the most recent error is "AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using `list.insert()` in an incorrect way.

Insert requires two parameters: the index and the element you want to insert.

```
index = 0 # Example
fulldeck[i]= fulldeck.insert(index, [name,speed,strength,agility,flexibility])
```

Or, you can always use list.append(), that requires no index since it always add the element to the end of the list.

```
 fulldeck[i]= fulldeck.append([name,speed,strength,agility,flexibility])
```